# how to add header Left to createMaterialTopTabNavigator?

Tags: react-native

I have createMaterialTopTabNavigator and createDrawerNavigator navigation system I want to add a menu bar icon to the screens of createMaterialTopTabNavigator , so I went to the screen/component and added this code , but nothing has been added and there is no errors at the console , could you please check my code if its correct

```
static.navigationOptions = {
      headerLeft:   () => { 
        return (  <Icon 
          name = 'menu'
          size = { focused ? 28 : 20}
          color = {tintColor}
          style={{paddingTop:20}}
        />)}}
```

Comment: headerLeft is an option for stackedNavigator not topTabNavigator. Take a look at https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/material-top-tab-navigator.html

Answer (score 3):

if you're trying to put the menu icon on top of the tabBar, you will have to use StackNavigator.

```
const TabPage = createMaterialTopNavigator({
 ...
})

const YNavigator = createStackNavigator ({
  Home:{screen: TabPage,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      headerLeft: <Icon name="home" size={15} color="blue" />,
    })
  },
})
```

hope this helps